# Local notification won't stop sending until I opened the app

Tags: c, xcode, notifications, local, appdelegate

my app won't stop sending the notification I set for a specific time until I opened the app. It will send me like every 2 minutes or so to kind of remind me...

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {

  NSCalendar *calendar3 = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
  NSDateComponents *components3 = [calendar3 components:(NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit |  NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit) fromDate:[NSDate date]];
  [components3 setHour:21];
  [components3 setMinute:30];
  UIApplication *app3 = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
  UILocalNotification *notifyAlarm3 = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
  if (notifyAlarm3) {
      notifyAlarm3.fireDate = [calendar3 dateFromComponents:components3];
      notifyAlarm3.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
      notifyAlarm3.repeatInterval = NSDayCalendarUnit;
      notifyAlarm3.soundName = @"not.wav";
      notifyAlarm3.alertBody = @"Hello";
      [app3 scheduleLocalNotification:notifyAlarm3];
  }
  }
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {
  UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
  NSArray *oldNotifications = [app scheduledLocalNotifications];
  if ([oldNotifications count] > 0) {
      [app cancelAllLocalNotifications];
  }
  }

Looking forward to response!

Comment: This actually does not happen every time. Sometimes I just get 1 notification and sometimes like 8...